# Clarification on Digital Certificates

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, certificate, digital-certificate

I used the makecert tool to create:

1. self-signed certificate
2. client certificate

These are the commands I used:

```
makecert -n "CN=MatthewCA" -r -sv MatthewCA.pvk MatthewCA.cer **for self signed certificate**

makecert -sk localhost -iv MatthewCA.pvk -n "CN=localhost" -ic MatthewCA.cer localhost.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe -b 01/01/2013 -e 01/01/2020 **for client certificate**
```

The two commands generated the following files:

1. MatthewCA.cer
2. MatthewCA.pvk
3. localhost.cer

I then installed MatthewCA.cer in the Trusted Root Authorities section in mmc.

The localhost.cer was installed in the Personal section in mmc.

When I view the certificate of localhost.cer from mmc, it says **You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate**.

Does this mean that the certificate contains the private key?  If I send the localhost.cer to someone else, can they extract the private key?  If yes, how can I seperate the private key from the certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you export the certificate from the store, you'll have a choice over whether to export the private key (the default is "no").

Windows maintains a link between the private key you own and the certificate, but the private key is not *embedded* in the certificate.

Comment: So if I send the localhost.cer created by makecert.exe to someone or upload it online, the recepients won't be able to extract the private key from the certificate.  Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, that's correct. Unless you explicitly choose to export the key with the cert, then only the cert is exported.